# Is this the proper way to detect an iPad?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios

Can I use the following code to detect if my app is running on iPad? My app needs to run on iOS 3.0 or higher.

```
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPad"]){
  //Do iPad stuff.
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` macro on iOS >= 3.2:

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
   //device is an iPad.
}
```

On earlier versions of iOS, you can fall back to your code, namely this:

```
NSRange ipadRange = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] rangeOfString:@"iPad"];
if(ipadRange.location != NSNotFound) {
  //Do iPad stuff.
}
```

This approach is forward-compatible in the sense that if next year Apple released a different iPad, the model name might change, but the word "iPad" will definitely be somewhere inside the string.

Comment: Had a good reason to use the currentDevice method today, even for a 5.0+ app: wanted to get some special behavior when running an iphone-only app on an ipad. UIUserInterfaceIdiom claims to be a phone in that case.

Answer (score 5):

Nope. Do this instead:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: To develop for iOS 3.2 and newer, you must be using a newer SDK that has `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` defined. It's a macro, and on earlier OS versions it devolves to always return `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone`. If you're using an older SDK, you won't be able to do iPad-specific development anyway as you won't be able to enable iPad targetting.