# How to get a cocos2d app to use iPad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have an iPhone app I developed using cocos2d.  I have the correct version which supports iPad.  Now, how do I get it to change the screen resolution or to recognize that it is an iPad app and not an iPhone app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM) to figure out in what kind of device your app is running. Anyway, you should always try to layout your stuff relative to the screen size (or the root view controller's view size) so that it will adapt itself to any resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your app use the entire iPad screen and not run in the simulator simply by changing the target device from iPhone to iPhone/iPad in Xcode. If you want your app to show different UI and run different code on the iPad, you can check for the device by using one of [several ways to detect an iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4567728/224988) in Objective-C.