# Swift add icon/image in UITextField

Tags: ios, image, swift, authentication, uitextfield

I would like to add icon/image in UITextField. The icon/image should be left to placeholder.

[image]

I tried this:

```
var imageView = UIImageView();
var image = UIImage(named: "email.png");
imageView.image = image;
emailField.leftView = imageView;
```

Thanks.

Comment: You accidentally added semicolons :D

Comment: `emailField.leftView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "search"))`
:)

Comment: Using `@IBDesignable` we can do this in an elegant way as in this example :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51841433/8238512

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Try adding `emailField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always`

(Default `leftViewMode` is `Never`)

Updated Answer for **Swift 4**

```
emailField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always

emailField.leftViewMode = .always
```

Comment: Hmm it worked for me, did you try it with the updated value (`UITextFieldViewMode.Always`)? Do you have any idea of what it was that didn't work? (for instance did it compile?)

Comment: This is my whole code in ' ViewWillAppear' section: ' var imageView = UIImageView();
        var image = UIImage(named: "email.png");
        imageView.image = image;
        emailTextField.leftView = imageView;
        emailTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always

Comment: @informatiker Ok, So are you sure that you have the connections correct, if you for example set the background color of the `emailTextField` does it really change? And are you sure that the image is there? For example, create an other UIImageView and load the `image` in that one to verify that that works.

Comment: yes, thanks. The issue was that the icon was white and wasn't visible on white background.

Comment: @Markus : hey, i'm using the same code but it didn't show the image? do you have any exaplanation?

Comment: @Sashi, not really... make sure that the image can be loaded by loading it in another `UIImageView` (and that it's not white on a white background)

Comment: I continued my search and finally got it to work, i missed setting up the frame for the image view. Look's like we need to set frame on image before adding it to the uitextfield. Something like this `imageView1.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 0, width: userName.frame.height, height: userName.frame.height)
      view.addSubview(imageView1)`

Comment: doesn't the placeholder overlap with the image?

Answer (score 141):

Sahil has a great answer and I wanted to take that and expand it into an @IBDesignable so developers can add images to their UITextFields on the Storyboard.

## Swift 4.2

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class DesignableUITextField: UITextField {
    
    // Provides left padding for images
    override func leftViewRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var textRect = super.leftViewRect(forBounds: bounds)
        textRect.origin.x += leftPadding
        return textRect
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var leftImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            updateView()
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var leftPadding: CGFloat = 0
    
    @IBInspectable var color: UIColor = UIColor.lightGray {
        didSet {
            updateView()
        }
    }
    
    func updateView() {
        if let image = leftImage {
            leftViewMode = UITextField.ViewMode.always
            let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            imageView.image = image
            // Note: In order for your image to use the tint color, you have to select the image in the Assets.xcassets and change the "Render As" property to "Template Image".
            imageView.tintColor = color
            leftView = imageView
        } else {
            leftViewMode = UITextField.ViewMode.never
            leftView = nil
        }
        
        // Placeholder text color
        attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder != nil ?  placeholder! : "", attributes:[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: color])
    }
}
```

**What is happening here?**

This designable allows you to:

- Set an image on the left
- Add padding between the left edge of the UITextField and the image
- Set a color so the image and the Placeholder text matches

**Notes**

- For image color to change you have to follow that note in the comment in the code
- The image color will not change in the Storyboard. You have to run the project to see the color in the Simulator/device.

**Designable in the Storyboard**
[image: Storyboard]

**At Runtime**
[image: Runtime]

Comment: Added in imageView.contentMode = .AspectFit, to avoid image resizing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great post! I've modified it to also have a RTL option. Code available here: http://pastebin.com/7CCm6NEB

Comment: @Ali Almohsen we don't need to write extra code for placing image on right side.you can select the Force Right-to-Left option in semantic in interface builder for image on right place.

Comment: what about padding between image and text?

Comment: Otherwise, well this can be used, set padding, a dummy image and the image outside of the textview.

Comment: There are some problems here. Setting the frame in updateView actually does nothing - iOS overrides it anyway  :/

Comment: How can we update this code to what @ZaporozhchenkoOleksandr commented to use the same leftPadding for the text?

Comment: For anyone wondering how to get padding between the image and the placeholder/text, add a UIView with a frame having a larger width, but the same height as the image in updateView(). Then add the imageView as a subview of the container, and set leftView to the container instead of imageView.

Comment: If you want to show updates on storyboard live, simply override prepareForInterfaceBuilder method and call updateView method.

Answer (score 58):

I Just want to add some more thing here:

If you want to add the image on `UITextField` on left side  use `leftView` property of `UITextField`

**NOTE:** **Don't forget to set `leftViewMode` to `UITextFieldViewMode.Always` and for right `rightViewMode` to `UITextFieldViewMode.Always and`default is `UITextFieldViewModeNever`**

for e.g

**For adding an image on left side**

```
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
imageView.image = image
textField.leftView = imageView
```

**For adding an image on right side**

```
textField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
imageView.image = image
textField.rightView = imageView
```

**NOTE:** some things you need to take care while adding an image on `UITextField` either on the left side or right side.

- Don't forget to give a frame of `ImageView` which are you going to add on `UITextField`

  let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
- if your image background is white then image won't visible on `UITextField`
- if you want to add an image to the specific position you need to add `ImageView` as the subview of `UITextField`.

**Update For Swift 3.0**

@Mark Moeykens Beautifully expended it and make it **@IBDesignable**.

I modified and added some more features (add Bottom Line and padding for right image) in this.

**NOTE** if you want to add an image on the right side you can select the `Force Right-to-Left` option in `semantic` in interface builder(But for right image padding won't work until you will override rightViewRect method ).

[image]

I have modified this and can download the source from here [ImageTextField](https://github.com/Sahilberi/ImageTextField)

[image]

Comment: how can i add this in extensions and call in my viewcontroller ? can you suggest me

Comment: Very simple! simply create function in  UIViewController extension and pass imagename and textfield ref when calling that function.

Comment: extension UIViewController {

  func addLeftImage(imageName: String, textField: UITextField) {
    textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    imageView.image = image
    textField.leftView = imageView
  
  }
}
and call it like       self.addLeftImage("imganame", textField: yourtextfield)

Comment: i tried to change icon position. but not changed using this code

Answer (score 28):

[image: UITextField with image (left or right)]

Another way, inspired from previous posts to make an extension.

We can put the image on the right or on the left

```
extension UITextField {

enum Direction {
    case Left
    case Right
}

// add image to textfield
func withImage(direction: Direction, image: UIImage, colorSeparator: UIColor, colorBorder: UIColor){
    let mainView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 45))
    mainView.layer.cornerRadius = 5

    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 45))
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    view.clipsToBounds = true
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    view.layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(0.5)
    view.layer.borderColor = colorBorder.cgColor
    mainView.addSubview(view)

    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 12.0, y: 10.0, width: 24.0, height: 24.0)
    view.addSubview(imageView)

    let seperatorView = UIView()
    seperatorView.backgroundColor = colorSeparator
    mainView.addSubview(seperatorView)

    if(Direction.Left == direction){ // image left
        seperatorView.frame = CGRect(x: 45, y: 0, width: 5, height: 45)
        self.leftViewMode = .always
        self.leftView = mainView
    } else { // image right
        seperatorView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 5, height: 45)
        self.rightViewMode = .always
        self.rightView = mainView
    }

    self.layer.borderColor = colorBorder.cgColor
    self.layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(0.5)
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
}

}
```

Use :

```
if let myImage = UIImage(named: "my_image"){
    textfield.withImage(direction: .Left, image: myImage, colorSeparator: UIColor.orange, colorBorder: UIColor.black)
}
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: You made my day, i customized the "view.backgroundColor" and the "imageView.tintColor" to make it full customizable. Thanks a lot for your answer xD

Comment: This is awesome

Comment: This is best and simple answers

Answer (score 18):

To create padding, I like to place the image inside of a container view. You can remove the background color once you are happy with the icon placement.

[image]

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 8.0, y: 8.0, width: 24.0, height: 24.0))
let image = UIImage(named: "my_icon")
imageView.image = image
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 32, height: 40))
view.addSubview(imageView)
view.backgroundColor = .green
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
textField.leftView = view
```

Comment: Thank you. Good explanation with colors.

Comment: most intelligent way as it makes shorter without extension on uitextfield

Answer (score 13):

for Swift 3.0 add image on leftside of textField

```
textField.leftView = UIImageView(image: "small-calendar")
textField.leftView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 5, width: 20 , height:20)
textField.leftViewMode = .always
```

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 5**

```
@IBOutlet weak var paswd: UITextField! {
    didSet{
      paswd.setLeftView(image: UIImage.init(named: "password")!)
      paswd.tintColor = .darkGray
      paswd.isSecureTextEntry = true
    }   
 }
```

I have created extension

```
extension UITextField {
  func setLeftView(image: UIImage) {
    let iconView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 25, height: 25)) // set your Own size
    iconView.image = image
    let iconContainerView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 35, height: 45))
    iconContainerView.addSubview(iconView)
    leftView = iconContainerView
    leftViewMode = .always
    self.tintColor = .lightGray
  }
}
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 8):

### 2024 - reasonable solution.

Regarding this insanity from Apple.

Here is perhaps the "clearest", simplest, way to do it:

[image]

### Even better, you now get the detailed image settings (image size, etc) for free in Xcode:

Notice you can set the symbol scale and so on.

[image]

First, you must correctly move the text.

***Note this critical QA: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27066764/294884***

```
class TidyTextField: UITextField {
    
    @IBInspectable var leftImage: UIImage? = nil
    @IBInspectable var leftPadding: CGFloat = 0
    @IBInspectable var gapPadding: CGFloat = 0
    
    private var textPadding: UIEdgeInsets {
        let p: CGFloat = leftPadding + gapPadding + (leftView?.frame.width ?? 0)
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: p, bottom: 0, right: 5)
    }
    
    override open func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.inset(by: textPadding)
    }
    
    override open func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.inset(by: textPadding)
    }
    
    override open func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.inset(by: textPadding)
    }
```

continuing, we now have to make and move the left image:

```
    override func leftViewRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var r = super.leftViewRect(forBounds: bounds)
        r.origin.x += leftPadding
        return r
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setup()
    }
    
    private func setup() {
        if let image = leftImage {
            if leftView != nil { return } // critical!
            
            let im = UIImageView()
            im.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            im.image = image
            
            leftViewMode = UITextField.ViewMode.always
            leftView = im
            
        } else {
            leftViewMode = UITextField.ViewMode.never
            leftView = nil
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to be about the clearest, most reliable way to do it.

Answer (score 7):

**Using the extension in Swift4, We can easily put the image on the right or on the left with padding to TextField.**

```
extension UITextField {

    //MARK:- Set Image on the right of text fields

  func setupRightImage(imageName:String){
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 20, height: 20))
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    let imageContainerView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 55, height: 40))
    imageContainerView.addSubview(imageView)
    rightView = imageContainerView
    rightViewMode = .always
    self.tintColor = .lightGray
}

 //MARK:- Set Image on left of text fields

    func setupLeftImage(imageName:String){
       let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 20, height: 20))
       imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
       let imageContainerView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 55, height: 40))
       imageContainerView.addSubview(imageView)
       leftView = imageContainerView
       leftViewMode = .always
       self.tintColor = .lightGray
     }

  }
```

Use code as for left image setup:-

```
   self.password_text_field.setupLeftImage(imageName: "unlock")
```

Output :)

[image]

Comment: Best way of doing this in my opinion. No need of storyboards. Simple and short. Nice job!

Comment: Excellent job......

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3.1

```
extension UITextField
{
    enum Direction
    {
        case Left
        case Right
    }

    func AddImage(direction:Direction,imageName:String,Frame:CGRect,backgroundColor:UIColor)
    {
        let View = UIView(frame: Frame)
        View.backgroundColor = backgroundColor

        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: Frame)
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)

        View.addSubview(imageView)

        if Direction.Left == direction
        {
            self.leftViewMode = .always
            self.leftView = View
        }
        else
        {
            self.rightViewMode = .always
            self.rightView = View
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: please add ussage and what I need to pass frame param ?

Comment: in this Function "Frame" Parameter Use for  left or right View

Answer (score 3):

I created a simple IBDesignable. Use it however u like. Just make your UITextField confirm to this class.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class RoundTextField : UITextField {
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius : CGFloat = 0{
        didSet{
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
            layer.masksToBounds = cornerRadius > 0
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth : CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet{
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderColor : UIColor? {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor?.cgColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var bgColor : UIColor? {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor = bgColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var leftImage : UIImage? {
        didSet {
            if let image = leftImage{
                leftViewMode = .always
                let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
                imageView.image = image
                imageView.tintColor = tintColor
                let view = UIView(frame : CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 20))
                view.addSubview(imageView)
                leftView = view
            }else {
                leftViewMode = .never
            }

        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var placeholderColor : UIColor? {
        didSet {
            let rawString = attributedPlaceholder?.string != nil ? attributedPlaceholder!.string : ""
            let str = NSAttributedString(string: rawString, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : placeholderColor!])
            attributedPlaceholder = str
        }
    }

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: 50, dy: 5)
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: 50, dy: 5)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]
Another way to set placeholder icon & set padding to TextField.

```
let userIcon = UIImage(named: "ImageName") 
setPaddingWithImage(image: userIcon, textField: txtUsername)

func setPaddingWithImage(image: UIImage, textField: UITextField){
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 50))
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 13.0, y: 13.0, width: 24.0, height: 24.0)
    //For Setting extra padding other than Icon.
    let seperatorView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 0, width: 10, height: 50))
    seperatorview.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 80/255, green: 89/255, blue: 94/255, alpha: 1)
    view.addSubview(seperatorView)
    textField.leftViewMode = .always
    view.addSubview(imageView)
    view.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
    textField.leftView = view
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put this function your global file or above your class so you can access it in entire application. 
     After this procedure you can call this function as per your requirement in application.

```
        func SetLeftSIDEImage(TextField: UITextField, ImageName: String){

                let leftImageView = UIImageView()
                leftImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

                let leftView = UIView()

                leftView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: 30, height: 20)
                leftImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 13, y: 0, width: 15, height: 20)
                TextField.leftViewMode = .always
                TextField.leftView = leftView

                let image = UIImage(named: ImageName)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
                leftImageView.image = image
                leftImageView.tintColor = UIColor(red: 106/255, green: 79/255, blue: 131/255, alpha: 1.0)
                leftImageView.tintColorDidChange()

                leftView.addSubview(leftImageView)
            }

            SetLeftSIDEImage(TextField: Your_textField, ImageName: “YourImageName”) // call function
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, is there some way you could povide some explanation along with this code?  Answers that only have code in them tend to get deleted for being low quality.  Please also take a look at this guide for answering in the help section: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

```
let image = UIImage(systemName: "envelope")
let textField = UITextField()
textField.leftView = UIImageView(image: image)
textField.leftView?.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: 20 , height:20)
textField.leftViewMode = .always
```

Comment: Please, provide an explanation about your answer, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go for the easiest approach. For most cases you want to add icons like font awesome... Just use font awesome library and it would be as easy to add an icon to an text field as this:

```
myTextField.setLeftViewFAIcon(icon: .FAPlus, leftViewMode: .always, textColor: .red, backgroundColor: .clear, size: nil)
```

You would need to install first this swift library:
https://github.com/Vaberer/Font-Awesome-Swift

Comment: Why should one add an entire library only to get one glyph?

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified version of Mark Moeykens' answer with added padding between image and text and adjustable image size in case somebody needs it.

**Swift 4**

```
    import UIKit

    @IBDesignable
    class TextFieldWithImage: UITextField {

        override func leftViewRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
            return super.leftViewRect(forBounds: bounds)
        }

        @IBInspectable var leftImage: UIImage? {
            didSet {
                updateView()
            }
        }
        @IBInspectable var leftPadding: CGFloat = 0 {
            didSet {
                updateView()
            }
        }
        @IBInspectable var rightPadding: CGFloat = 0 {
            didSet {
                updateView()
            }
        }
        @IBInspectable var imageMaxHeight: CGFloat = 0 {
            didSet {
                updateView()
            }
        }

        @IBInspectable var color: UIColor = UIColor.lightGray {
            didSet {
                updateView()
            }
        }

        func updateView() {
            if let image = leftImage {
                leftViewMode = UITextField.ViewMode.always

                let containerSize = calculateContainerViewSize(for: image)
                let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: containerSize.width, height: containerSize.height))

                let imageView = UIImageView(frame: .zero)
                containerView.addSubview(imageView)
                setImageViewConstraints(imageView, in: containerView)

                setImageViewProperties(imageView, image: image)

                leftView = containerView
            } else {
                leftViewMode = UITextField.ViewMode.never
                leftView = nil
            }

            attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder != nil ? placeholder! : "",
                    attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: color])
        }

        private func calculateContainerViewSize(for image: UIImage) -> CGSize {
            let imageRatio = image.size.height / image.size.width
            let adjustedImageMaxHeight = imageMaxHeight > self.frame.height ? self.frame.height : imageMaxHeight

            var imageSize = CGSize()
            if image.size.height > adjustedImageMaxHeight {
                imageSize.height = adjustedImageMaxHeight
                imageSize.width = imageSize.height / imageRatio
            }

            let paddingWidth = leftPadding + rightPadding

            let containerSize = CGSize(width: imageSize.width + paddingWidth, height: imageSize.height)
            return containerSize
        }

        private func setImageViewConstraints(_ imageView: UIImageView, in containerView: UIView) {
            imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -rightPadding).isActive = true
            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: leftPadding).isActive = true
        }

        private func setImageViewProperties(_ imageView: UIImageView, image: UIImage) {
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            imageView.image = image
            imageView.tintColor = color
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

Similar to @Markus, but in **Swift 5**:

```
emailTextField.leftViewMode = UITextField.ViewMode.always
emailTextField.leftViewMode = .always
```

Answer (score 0):

**SwiftUI**

```
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50)
                .frame(height: 40)
                .colorInvert() // sets the background white
            .padding()
            .shadow(radius: 12) // adds shadow to the rectangle
                .overlay(
                    HStack(spacing: 20){

                        Image(systemName: "person")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)

                        TextField("Username ", text: $username)
                            .font(Font.custom("Arial", size: 25))


                            .font(.title)
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .padding()
                )
```

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tae2Y.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that frame-based solutions are a good approach, because it won't be available on an iPad in some cases.
The ideal solution would be to add constraints from imageView to textfield right view, but it's not that easy. The right view does not appear to be in textfield view hierarchy unless it is required, so you need to do the following:

```swift
    private let countryTextField: UITextField = {
        let countryTextField = UITextField()
        countryTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        countryTextField.rightViewMode = .always
        
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "yourImageName"), for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        countryTextField.rightView = button
        countryTextField.setNeedsLayout() //Add rightView in textField hierarchy
        countryTextField.layoutIfNeeded() //Add rightView in textField hierarchy
        
        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: countryTextField.topAnchor).isActive = true
        button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: countryTextField.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: countryTextField.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        
        return countryTextField
    }()
```

And the result on any device is:

[image: TextField right view]

Also, my solution works with textfield left view.

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me. in a custom/reusable class. helps alot with the space in  b/w the actual text and left view icon/image  [image]

```
func currencyLeftVeiw(image litery: UIImage) {
        self.leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
        self.leftViewMode = .always
        let leftViewItSelf = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 20, height: 20))
        leftViewItSelf.image = litery
        leftView?.addSubview(leftViewItSelf)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To go off @Mark Moeykens's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41151566/6901471), I made some slight adjustments so that it fixed some issues that I was getting:

1. The images I have in my project are much larger than the image view size (since I'm using them in different parts of the app as well), which was causing the size of the image view to be much larger than necessary.
2. Gives horizontal padding even if you don't have an image
3. Allows you to set spacing between the image and the text

The different values can be adjusted in the `Constants` enum.

Credit goes to @Mark Moeykens

```
import UIKit

final class PaddingWithImageTextField: UITextField {
    private enum Constants {
        static let iconLength: CGFloat = 24.0
        static let imageTextSpacing: CGFloat = 8.0
        static let horizontalPadding: CGFloat = 12.0
        static let placeholderColor = UIColor.lightGray
    }

    var leftImage: UIImage? { didSet { updateView() } }
    var rightImage: UIImage? { didSet { updateView() } }
    override var placeholder: String? {
        didSet {
            attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder != nil ?  placeholder! : "", attributes:[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: Constants.placeholderColor])
        }
    }

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        // Any additional setup you may need.
        /*
        layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        clipsToBounds = true
        keyboardType = .asciiCapable
        backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#F5F5F5")
        */

        updateView()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func updateView() {
        leftViewMode = .always
        rightViewMode = .always
        if let image = leftImage {
            // Setting the rendering mode allows us to set the tint color and change the entire color of the image.
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate))
            imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: Constants.iconLength).isActive = true
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: Constants.iconLength).isActive = true
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            imageView.tintColor = Constants.placeholderColor
            let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [
                createHorizontalPaddingView(),
                imageView,
                createImageToTextPaddingView()
            ])
            stack.axis = .horizontal
            leftView = stack
        } else {
            leftView = createHorizontalPaddingView()
        }

        if let image = rightImage {
            // Setting the rendering mode allows us to set the tint color and change the entire color of the image.
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate))
            imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: Constants.iconLength).isActive = true
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: Constants.iconLength).isActive = true
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            imageView.tintColor = Constants.placeholderColor
            let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [
                createImageToTextPaddingView(),
                imageView,
                createHorizontalPaddingView()
            ])
            stack.axis = .horizontal
            rightView = stack
        } else {
            rightView = createHorizontalPaddingView()
        }
    }

    private func createHorizontalPaddingView() -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: Constants.horizontalPadding).isActive = true
        return view
    }

    private func createImageToTextPaddingView() -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: Constants.imageTextSpacing).isActive = true
        return view
    }
}
```

To use this class you can do something like this:

```
let textField = PaddingWithImageTextField()
textField.placeholder = "Code"
textField.leftImage = UIImage() // Your image here
textField.rightImage = UIImage() // Your other image here
```

which should give you something like the following image (depending on how you set up the text field in the initializer).

[image]