# Swift add image or icon in UITextField

Tags: swift

I would like to add icon/image in UITextfield .The Icon/Image should be left to placeholder.I tried this coding but it is not showing icon/image inside the textfield .

```
var imageView = UIImageView();

var image = UIImage(named: "usericon.png");

imageView.image = image;

username.leftView = imageView;

username.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
```

Comment: Why is it not working? Compilation error? Undesired/unexpected result? Runtime exception?

Comment: It is not showing any error.But,I don't know why this code doesn't work

Comment: You should describe in your question what's wrong with your code, what's actually not working - no image shown, image shown in wrong place, etc. Also give some info about what `username` is. Please update the question and do **not** add as comment

Comment: I want to design username textfield with icon using swift.I have used these codes but  it is not showing icon inside the UITextfield.

Comment: You can also try looking at a similar question here for answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903500/swift-add-icon-image-in-uitextfield/41151566#41151566

Comment: try this library in swift 3 https://github.com/Sahilberi/ImageTextField

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you forgot to add this code:

```
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200)
view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Image will show if u use this code.

May be this will help you.

Answer (score 4):

And In order to leave a space between the icon and the text

```
let imageView = UIImageView();
let image = UIImage(named: "icon_calendar");
imageView.image = image;
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 20, height: 20)
textfield.addSubview(imageView)
let leftView = UIView.init(frame: CGRectMake(10, 0, 30, 30))
textfield.leftView = leftView;
textfield.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
```