# Hiding Caps lock icon Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, capslock, jpasswordfield

Probably an easy fix, but how can I hide the "up arrow" icon (looks like ⬆️) on password fields when when the users turns on caps lock. Just to be clear, I want them to be able to turn on the caps lock, but not see the icon on text field.

The project is gonna be on iOS and Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a simple way to do this. Looks like other people have had success by setting the right-view of the UIView to an empty/blank view.

See:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43857539/57114

If you're using Xamarin Forms, the easiest way to do this is with an effect. Let me know if you want some help creating one.