# Customise UITextField in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

How to achieve below screen using UITextField in swift 3 IOS.

[image]

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @Anil You want to customise UITextField or UITextView.

Comment: Check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903500/swift-add-icon-image-in-uitextfield

Answer (score 0):

Do like this ...

- Add `UIImageView` for the left side icon image, set required image and background color
- Add `UITextField` beside the imageview and set border style to 'no border style' in interface builder (storyboard)
- Set the required background color
- Do the same for password field also, and for the eye icon view have a look at this https://github.com/Sahilberi/ImageTextField

Answer (score 0):

1. Add **UITextField**
2. Add subview as **imageView**
3. set Alpha of **UITextField**

Below sample code for that:

```
func addTextField() {
        let txtUserName = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 70, width: 320, height: 45))
        let txtPassword = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 140, width: 320, height: 45))
        txtUserName.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        txtPassword.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

        txtUserName.alpha = 0.35
        txtPassword.alpha = 0.35

        let imgUser = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: 35, height: 35))
        let imgKey = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: 35, height: 35))
        let imgEye = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: txtPassword.frame.size.width - 40, y: 5, width: 35, height: 35))
        imgUser.image = UIImage(named: "user")
        imgKey.image = UIImage(named: "key")
        imgEye.image = UIImage(named: "eye")
        txtUserName.addSubview(imgUser)
        txtPassword.addSubview(imgKey)
        txtPassword.addSubview(imgEye)
        view.addSubview(txtUserName)
        view.addSubview(txtPassword)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtpassword: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtUserName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtView: UITextView! //your textView


override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    //navigationBarColor()
    setTextFieldSpace( textField :txtUserName)
    setTextFieldSpace( textField :txtpassword)
    //textField border
    txtpassword.borderStyle = .none
    txtUserName.borderStyle = .none

}

//MARK: - Button Action
// password show hide
@IBAction func btnShowPasswordClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if txtpassword.isSecureTextEntry{
        txtpassword.isSecureTextEntry = false
    }else{
        txtpassword.isSecureTextEntry = true
    }
}

//for set space in left side of textField
func setTextFieldSpace( textField :UITextField){
    let lblSpace = UILabel()
    lblSpace.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 5, height: 5)
    lblSpace.backgroundColor = .clear
    textField.leftView = lblSpace

    textField.leftViewMode = .always
    textField.contentVerticalAlignment =  .center
}
```

}

//Check out this Out put

[image: your screen]