# Swift: how to create an image on the left side of a text field?

Tags: ios, swift

I have got a text field:

```
let usn_text_field: UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.placeholder = "Username"
        tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tf.background = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "usericon2")
        return tf
    }()
```

This textfield shows an input field with an image expanded. But I want a simple icon on the left of the input, how can i resize and reposition the image?

Comment: See this question: [Swift add icon/image in UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903500/swift-add-icon-image-in-uitextfield)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `leftView` attribute of the text field and put a `UIImageView` there to place an image to the left side of your text field.

```
tf.leftView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "usericon2"))
```

If you want to show it always, change the leftViewMode property of the text field:

```
tf.leftViewMode = .always
```

Comment: But what about size? It's still big

Comment: You can resize it by changing its `frame`.

Comment: Okay,thanks for thy answers.I shall accept it as soon as stackoverflow lets me:)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `leftView` property of `UITextField`

```
let textField : UITextField = UITextField()
textField.leftView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "your_image"))
textField.leftViewMode = .always
```

Comment: Thanks for your heuristic answer,but i think you forgot about `tf.leftViewMode = .always`,my code didn't work without it.