# Add icon or image in UITextField on left / right in Swift 4

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitextfield, swift4

I have set up the left icon in `UITextField`. When I set text, it is over the left icon. I want to set text after the icon in the `UITextField`. I have used below code.

```
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: strImgname))
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageView.image!.size.width , height: imageView.image!.size.height)
    let paddingView: UIView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 30))        
    paddingView.addSubview(imageView)
    txtField.leftViewMode = .always
    txtField.leftView = paddingView
```

Comment: Also updated my answer please follow the steps an in the updated answer to get easy and desired functionality.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `@IBDesignable` to make a designable `UITextField` with these capabilities and even more and use it through out your project.

**DesignableTextField with Delegate methods when icon in `UITextField` is tapped:**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol DesignableTextFieldDelegate: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldIconClicked(btn:UIButton)
}

@IBDesignable
class DesignableTextField: UITextField {

    //Delegate when image/icon is tapped.
    private var myDelegate: DesignableTextFieldDelegate? {
        get { return delegate as? DesignableTextFieldDelegate }
    }

    @objc func buttonClicked(btn: UIButton){
        self.myDelegate?.textFieldIconClicked(btn: btn)
    }

    //Padding images on left
    override func leftViewRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var textRect = super.leftViewRect(forBounds: bounds)
        textRect.origin.x += padding
        return textRect
    }

    //Padding images on Right
    override func rightViewRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var textRect = super.rightViewRect(forBounds: bounds)
        textRect.origin.x -= padding
        return textRect
    }

    @IBInspectable var padding: CGFloat = 0
    @IBInspectable var leadingImage: UIImage? { didSet { updateView() }}
    @IBInspectable var color: UIColor = UIColor.lightGray { didSet { updateView() }}
    @IBInspectable var imageColor: UIColor = UIColor.init(hex: "3EB2FF") { didSet { updateView() }}
    @IBInspectable var rtl: Bool = false { didSet { updateView() }}

    func updateView() {
        rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.never
        rightView = nil
        leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.never
        leftView = nil

        if let image = leadingImage {
            let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
            button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)

            let tintedImage = image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
            button.setImage(tintedImage, for: .normal)
            button.tintColor = imageColor

            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.clear, for: .normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked(btn:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchDown)
            button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

            if rtl {
                rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
                rightView = button
            } else {
                leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
                leftView = button
            }
        }

        // Placeholder text color
        attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholder != nil ?  placeholder! : "", attributes:[NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: color])
    }
}
```

**Now its Designable in the Storyboard as follows:**

[image]
**NOTE:** `Rtl` when set to `Off` icon will move to left of `UITextField`

**Conforming the Delegate in desired ViewController.**

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, DesignableTextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var txtFieldSomeSearch: DesignableTextField!
    txtFieldSomeSearch.delegate = self // can be done in storyboard as well
    ... // other codes
    func textFieldIconClicked(btn: UIButton) {
        print("MyViewController : textFieldIconClicked")
    }
    ... // other codes
}
```

**Finally Output :**

[image]

Comment: @EnamulHaque You should mark the answer accepted if the answer has solved the problem for you. It is the least you can do considering that people from the community take time out of their day to help a stranger with his problems. Also it helps other people having the same problem identify which is the best solution.

Comment: Thanks very much! Note that if the device language is set to an RTL language, the meaning of leftView and rightView is switched. They actually behave properly as "leadingView" and "trailingView". So the "rtl" property here might actually confuse things - if you set it to true and you are on a device set to an RTL language, you actually will end up with the opposite of the desired result.

Comment: @Rizwan, how do you ensure the text doesn't overlap the button when button is right aligned?

Answer (score 8):

**Using the extension in *Swift4*, We can easily put the image on the right or on the left with padding to TextField.**

```
extension UITextField {

    //MARK:- Set Image on the right of text fields

  func setupRightImage(imageName:String){
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 20, height: 20))
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    let imageContainerView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 55, height: 40))
    imageContainerView.addSubview(imageView)
    rightView = imageContainerView
    rightViewMode = .always
    self.tintColor = .lightGray
}

 //MARK:- Set Image on left of text fields

    func setupLeftImage(imageName:String){
       let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 20, height: 20))
       imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
       let imageContainerView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 55, height: 40))
       imageContainerView.addSubview(imageView)
       leftView = imageContainerView
       leftViewMode = .always
       self.tintColor = .lightGray
     }

  }
```

Use code as for right image setup:-

```
self.password_text_field.setupRightImage(imageName: "unlock")
```

Output :)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
please use the below code

//Left side icon
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
imageView.image = image
textField.leftView = imageView


//Right side icon
textField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
imageView.image = image
textField.rightView = imageView
```

Comment: Some writings would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Extension to `UITextField` in Swift 5. This allows you to check if the image is a system image, otherwise, you use a custom image. You can also set which side of the text field you want the image on using the `TextFieldImageSide` enumeration.

```
enum TextFieldImageSide {
    case left
    case right
}

extension UITextField {
    func setUpImage(imageName: String, on side: TextFieldImageSide) {
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 30, height: 30))
        if let imageWithSystemName = UIImage(systemName: imageName) {
            imageView.image = imageWithSystemName
        } else {
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        }
        
        let imageContainerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 45, height: 40))
        imageContainerView.addSubview(imageView)
        
        switch side {
        case .left:
            leftView = imageContainerView
            leftViewMode = .always
        case .right:
            rightView = imageContainerView
            rightViewMode = .always
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
searchBar.setUpImage(imageName: "mappin.and.ellipse", on: .left)
```

Produces the following:
[image]