# Need to move the cell inside the uicollectionview cell && Textfield image adding

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, textfield

need to move the collection view cell accordingly. I have attached my screenshot for your reference:
[image]

the above is my current image but I need that to be like this:
[image]

Then I need to add image to the textfield but I have added some code but I could not add it

```
searchtextfield.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
searchtextfield.leftView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "search"))
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please edit your post and add a minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example <https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve>  - otherwise it is hard to tell what the exact problem is. You may want to have a look at <https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask> too.

Comment: For Left View Mode : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903500/swift-add-icon-image-in-uitextfield

Answer (score 0):

For the collection view cell width and height you have to use below method:

```
extension "Your Controller" : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width/2 - 15, height: collectionView.frame.size.width/2 - 15)
    }
}
```

To make the the cell square I have added the with and height same. You can change it according to your requirement. The collection view width changes for different devices so you have to change the cell width and height too.

Don't forget to do the change in this too according to your requirement:

[image]

Hope this helps.