# Auto layout for iPad and iPhones

Tags: swift, autolayout

[image]

Anyone please suggest which contraint combination is best for getting this desired output. It must be suitable for both iPad and iPhones. First I set the label **To** in the center of the container and set contrainst for all other controls based on that. But the problem is there are lot more space left and the design looks not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have one Horizontal `UIStackView` with Distribution Fill Equally and inside I would put two horizontal `UIStackView`s with Distributions Fill. Inside each I would put `UILabel` and then `UITextField`.

Spacing between label and text field (or between stack views) you can set by setting spacing of its related stack view. Or you can set distribution to Fill Proportionally and then set aspect ratio for label and text field widths

[image]

So, constraints which you need are constraints for main stack view.

Comment: Is the inner stackviews requires any contraints ?

Comment: @SIDHARTHPU you can set spacing between or set dirstribution fill proportionally and then set aspect ratio For label and text field width

Comment: I also need calender icon inside both text field.

Comment: @SIDHARTHPU I would look for something called left view in text field. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903500/swift-add-icon-image-in-uitextfield)