# set the padding of a text field using swift in xcode

Tags: ios, swift

How to create some space at the beginning of a text field using swift? 
I looked at the post

[padding of text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367502/how-do-i-create-space-at-beginning-of-uitextfield-swift)

I don't understand what the subclass is doing and how do I use that class to padding.

Thank you very much

Comment: I think this answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/46730692/8231150

Answer (score 16, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27066764/846780

This answer is very clear,

1. If you subclass `UITextField` you can override `textRectForBounds`, `editingRectForBounds` and `placeholderRectForBounds`. These methods just allow you to add a rect (frame) to your textfield's label.
2. `newBounds` method create the rect (frame) that will be added to textfield's label.
3. Finally your padding is: `let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 5);`
4. Now you have a custom UITextField that has a custom padding.
5. If you create your new subClass like this `class MyTextField: UITextField` for example, you only need to change the class of the UITextField that you've added into IB file.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I forgot to change the class of my textfield to the new subclass. The padding is set to the default padding right now which is (top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 5). What if I want to modify the padding without editing the subclass every time?  I added this to the viewController "myTextField.textRectForBounds(CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))" as I want get more padding from the left. But nothing changed. Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 15):

Complementing the answer of **klevison-matias** this is the code I use when I want to add a padding to my TextField in Swift 3

```
//UITextField : override textRect, editingRect 
class LeftPaddedTextField: UITextField {

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x + 10, y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height)
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x + 10, y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height)
    }

}
```

Then in my TextField I use in this way:

```
let emailTextField: LeftPaddedTextField = {
    let textField = LeftPaddedTextField()
    textField.placeholder = "Enter email"
    textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    textField.layer.borderWidth = 1
    textField.keyboardType = .emailAddress
    return textField
}()

let passwordTextField: LeftPaddedTextField = {
    let textField = LeftPaddedTextField()
    textField.placeholder = "Enter password"
    textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    textField.layer.borderWidth = 1
    textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
    return textField
}()
```

Comment: Don't you have to subtract your insets from width of returned CGRect? Otherwise your text will block clearTextIndicator or other views contained in UITextField.

Answer (score 11):

Create TextField outlet and use following code. Say "nameTextField" has to add padding.

```
let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
nameTextField.leftView = paddingView
nameTextField.leftViewMode = .always
nameTextField.placeholder = "Enter Name"
```

You can add Image in paddingView.

Answer (score 4):

Based on @Jorge Casariego's answer I came up with this solution.

You can set `PaddedTextField` class and the desired padding through the Interface Builder!

```
class PaddedTextField: UITextField {

    @IBInspectable var padding: CGFloat = 0

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x + padding, y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.width - padding * 2, height: bounds.height)
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x + padding, y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.width - padding * 2, height: bounds.height)
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally! Something that works well when your text field has the clear button.

Answer (score 3):

full code sample:
make sure your TextField points to RoundedTextField via Story board

```
import UIKit

class RoundedTextField: UITextField {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        // add rounded corner
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
        self.clipsToBounds = false

        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    // For the padding from the left
    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x + 15.0, y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height)
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x + 15.0, y: bounds.origin.y, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height)
    }
}
```