# Adding spaces in front of text field via subclassing

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

So I am currently trying to add some space before my text in a text field. So when I type, it starts with four spaces instead of none. So I did some research and I came across something that seems really good (as indicated by all the votes), i.e., [Create space at the beginning of a UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367502/how-do-i-create-space-at-beginning-of-uitextfield-swift). One problem is that I do not know how to actually implement this in my other classes (assuming that's what the post is intending the reader to do).

This is what I think I'm supposed to do. I think I'm supposed to instantiate an object of that class and use the methods in the class to add spaces in front of my text field. But I don't actually know what that looks like in code. Could anyone give me an example of how to actually implement the code on this post? [Create space at the beginning of a UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367502/how-do-i-create-space-at-beginning-of-uitextfield-swift)

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
import UIKit

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var facebookButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var googleplusButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var fullNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailAddressTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        facebookButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        googleplusButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5

        fullNameTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
        fullNameTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        emailAddressTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
        emailAddressTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        passwordTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
        passwordTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

    }
}
```

Comment: you can set `LeftView` property in `TextField` to add some margin on left, same is for right side `RightView` alongwith it set visibility property of it.

Comment: Could you please give me an example? I know I don't set it to an integer and it has to be of type UIView...

Answer (score 1):

You need to create subclass of `UITextField`. Then add this code in its implementation

```
static CGFloat leftMargin = 10;
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    bounds.origin.x += leftMargin;
    bounds.size.width -= (leftMargin + 20);
    return bounds;
}
- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    bounds.origin.x += leftMargin;
    bounds.size.width -= (leftMargin + 20);
    return bounds;
}
```

After that, set custom class to your `UITextField`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. I know how to set the sub class. But I'm not sure how to actually implement the subclass in my other classes. So in my SignUpViewController class, how would I implement this subclass?

Comment: You need to create new class and set Subclass Type UITextfield then  past code in .M file, after you don't need to implement subclass in your class.

Then you ca select subclass from UITextfield property

Comment: Oh I see... So it would be something like this? `fullNameTextField.textRectForBounds(CGRect)` But what goes in the parameter exactly? In other words, what do I put inside the parenthesis?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a class from @ScareCrow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367502/how-do-i-create-space-at-beginning-of-uitextfield-swift). After that go to the storyboard and change the class of the `UITextField`. Such as:
[image]

After that create an IBOutlet of the textfield. That outlet will be instance of the `TextField` class.

Comment: So I don't have to do anything like, `fullNameTextField.textRectForBounds(CGRect)` or something?

Comment: So what should I do after I create an instance of that class? There still isn't any space. I apologize for my noobness. I don't actually understand what is going in the code there.

Comment: You should call the `NewBounds` method. As a parameter set your outlet bounds. That will return your new bounds.