# Creating padding through Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitextfield

I was using this post as reference: [Create space at the beginning of a UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367502/how-do-i-create-space-at-beginning-of-uitextfield-swift). And in this post, there is a very helpful class adding padding in a textfield. However, the only way that I know how to use this class is for me to programmatically create a textfield. But instead, I would like to use this class with an IBOutlet. Here is the TextField Class:

```
class TextField: UITextField {

    let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 35, bottom: 0, right: 5);

    override func textRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return self.newBounds(bounds)
    }

    override func placeholderRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return self.newBounds(bounds)
    }

    override func editingRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return self.newBounds(bounds)
    }

    private func newBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        print("paisjdpfij")
        var newBounds = bounds
        newBounds.origin.x += padding.left
        newBounds.origin.y += padding.top
        newBounds.size.height -= padding.top + padding.bottom
        newBounds.size.width -= padding.left + padding.right
        return newBounds
    }
}
```

And here is my attempt to use it with my IBOutlet:

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstNameTextField: TextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    firstNameTextField = TextField()

}
```

However, the there is still no padding in the textfield. Anybody have a solution to this problem?

Now, I used this code:

```
let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 10.0, width: 5.0, height: 20.0))

        firstNameTextField.leftView = paddingView
        firstNameTextField.leftViewMode = .Always
```

to add padding on the left side of the textfield. However, I would also like some padding on the bottom as well. And there doesn't seem to be a simple solution for adding a bottom padding.

Answer (score 0):

you can create category/extension or create custom text field as you did. And implement this 2 methods and play with it by changing different bounds.

```
import UIKit

class CustomTextField: UITextField 
{

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func textRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect 
    {
        return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + 10, bounds.origin.y + 8, bounds.size.width - 20, bounds.size.height - 16);
    }

    override func editingRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect 
    {
        return self.textRectForBounds(bounds);
    }
}
```

For more detail you can refer this Nate Flink's answer at here:[Set padding for UITextField with UITextBorderStyleNone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727068/set-padding-for-uitextfield-with-uitextborderstylenone)