# How do I indent part of the text in a UITextView

Tags: swift, string, text, swift3, uitextview

I want to indent part of the text in a UITextView

Original:

```
Paragraph Here:
Hello World this is just a test. 
Hello World this is just a test.
Hello World this is just a test
```

How do I make it show up like this

```
Paragraph Here:
    Hello World this is just a test. 
    Hello World this is just a test.
    Hello World this is just a test
```

I don't want to use spaces in the beggining because if the device is really small it will mess it all up

Comment: This should help
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367502/create-space-at-the-beginning-of-a-uitextfield/27066764#27066764](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367502/create-space-at-the-beginning-of-a-uitextfield/27066764#27066764)

Comment: @Tom Can I add padding to part of the textView and not the whole thing

Answer (score 1):

```
var textMessage = "Paragraph Here:\nHello World this is just a test.\nHello World this is just a test.\nHello World this is just a test"
    textMessage = textMessage.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "\n\t")
    textView.text = textMessage
```

Try the above code. 
I hope it helps you.

Comment: The text is gonna be like 20 sentences long and I want all of them to be tabbed. I can't do it at a certain place because it will be different depending on what device the person is using.

Comment: Then You have to be use padding to UITextView.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else looking at this problem, I found a solution on this blog:

https://bendodson.com/weblog/2018/08/09/bulleted-lists-with-uilabel/

> "The bulk of the heavy lifting is done by an NSParagraphStyle
>   attribute called headIndent which adds a fixed amount of padding to
>   all but the first line of a paragraph"

Answer (score 0):

Id use the "\t" to create a tab.

```
       let  string = "\tHello World this is just a test."
```

Comment: The text is gonna be like 20 sentences long and I want all of them to be tabbed. I can't do it at a certain place because it will be different depending on what device the person is using.

Answer (score 0):

If you want each line in new row then use new line. Sample code

```
let textMessage = "Hello World this is just a test.\nHello World this is just a test.\nHello World this is just a test"
self.textView.text = textMessage
```

or if you want to leave a bit of space at the beginning of a UITextView then use it

```
 textView.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(10, 0, 0)
```

Comment: The text is gonna be like 20 sentences long and I want all of them to be tabbed. I can't do it at a certain place because it will be different depending on what device the person is using.