# Swift textfield inside left side add icon

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add icon inside the Textfield. Here, I am using multiple textfield with separate icons, I need to create subclass for adding left icon.

Here below my code for single textfield

```
var imageView = UIImageView();
var image = UIImage(named: "user-icon.png");
imageView.image = image;
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0, 20, 19);
usernameTextField.leftView = imageView;
usernameTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this One is Working **(Swift 4 Code)**

```
extension UITextField{

    func setLeftImage(imageName:String) {

        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        self.leftView = imageView;
        self.leftViewMode = .always
    }
}
```

**Use Like this :**

```
YourtextField.setLeftImage(imageName: "image_name")
```

Comment: i am sorry I am looking subclass for this.

Comment: @ApplePrime You can give separate icons name for each text field by using this one.

Comment: Hi, Could you please le me know why we are using button for this, can able to use UIView here? @Nikunj Kumbhani

Comment: @ApplePrime Yes you can add either image view or UIView whatever you want. Check Updated answer is with UIImageView.

Comment: icon sizes not sitting properly, I am doing universal application. I am getting bit spaces from left to icon and not much spaces between icon and placeholder. @Nikunj Kumbhani

Comment: @ApplePrime Add this Class into Project and assign that to your text field. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27066764/10150796