# How can I add an inset to the text and placeholder in PhoneNumberTextField

Tags: ios, swift, phonenumberkit

I need to use a textfield to havet he user type in phone numbers so I'm using the `PhoneNumberTextField` from the project [PhoneNumberKit](https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit).

By default it's just a borderless textfield. I modified it by adding a border with a corner radius and a `UIButton` added to its `leftView`. The problem with that is the text/placeholder is shown right up against the border.

[image]

[image]

I tried subclassing `PhoneNumberTextField` and adding the text inset capability like this.

```swift
@IBDesignable
class CNPhoneNumberTextField: PhoneNumberTextField {
    @IBInspectable var inset: CGFloat = 0

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: inset, dy: inset)
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: inset, dy: inset)
    }

    override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.insetBy(dx: inset, dy: inset)
    }
}
```

The issue here is it doesn't take the `leftView` into account now. The text/placeholder is partially covered by the `leftView`.

[image]

Is there any other way to fix this?

[Demo project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mid7069shpl2iqw/PhoneText.zip?dl=0)

Comment: I think the problem is in the layer you are adding for rounding text field.

Comment: Instead of button why don't you use image view and add tap gesture to it.

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger I tried with an `UIImageView` and a `UIView` as the `leftView`. Still the issue persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your `CNPhoneNumberTextField` class like shown below where you can give `leftPadding` for your `textField` from storyboard.

Your class will look like:

```
import UIKit
import PhoneNumberKit

@IBDesignable
class CNPhoneNumberTextField: PhoneNumberTextField {

    @IBInspectable var leftPadding: CGFloat = 0

    override open func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {

        let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: leftPadding, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        return bounds.inset(by: padding)
    }

    override open func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {

        let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: leftPadding, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        return bounds.inset(by: padding)
    }

    override open func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {

        let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: leftPadding, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        return bounds.inset(by: padding)
    }
}
```

And from storyboard with Attribute inspector section you can assign left padding like:

[image]

And your result will be:

[image]

Reference from [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367502/create-space-at-the-beginning-of-a-uitextfield) answer.

**EDIT:**

[HERE](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=05308168981742313304) is the demo project.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. For some reason, it's still not working for me. Can you please attach the Xcode project?

Comment: Yes sure. Will do it.

Comment: I see. You increased the padding value to a bigger number so it will go past the `leftView`. I was wondering why the textRect doesn't take the `leftView`'s bounds into account.

Comment: It's taking `leftView`'s bounds into account thats why you are getting result which you showed in you first image in your question

Answer (score 0):

You could probably add some padding like this:

```
override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    var rect = super.textRect(forBounds: bounds)
    rect.origin.x += 10
    return rect
}
```