# Position "Clear Button" in UITextfield

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Is there a way to position the clear button? I would like to move it down by just a little bit so it's on the same level with the text input. Any ideas?

My Textfields are already Subclasses of another Class that handles the effects. Including the "clearButtonRect" function doesn't work.

```
@IBDesignable open class HoshiTextField: TextFieldEffects {

//effect functions..

    override open func clearButtonRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: 0, y: 0.2, width: 0.1, height: 0.3)
        }
    }`
```

[image]

Comment: What you used for that clear button some custom button or used textfield property?

Comment: firstNameTextField.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing

Comment: thats the only code regarding the clear button

Comment: @Chris you can try this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27066764/3683408

Comment: What is an easy way to find out my coordinate values for the clear button?

Comment: @Chris CGRect(x: 0, y:5.0, width: yourButtonWidth, height: yourButtonHeight) - Hope it's clear to you:)

Comment: My Problem right now is, that my Textfields are already a subclass of TextFieldEffects. I just created the subclass CustomClearButton but how do I make it work now ?

Comment: Hope you can understand what I mean, look at my other comment below:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subclass your textfield and override the `clearButtonRect` function

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    override func clearButtonRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: xPos, y:yPos, width: yourWidth, height: yourHeight)
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1 - Subclass 3rd party Textfield**

As you are using 3rd party library calls TextFieldEffects you will need to follow the below steps.

If you you are using storyboard and have a textfield on there (set the class to CustomTextField)

[image: Setting CustomTextField Class]

if you can doing it programmatically you will need to change it there.

Then create a new swift file call it CustomTextField.swift and add the below code

```
import UIKit
import TextFieldEffects // Import the 3rd party library

// Now you are subclassing the 3rd party textfield
// Change it to the textfield you are using and if you are using multiple create subclass for individual ones.
class CustomTextField: HoshiTextField {

    override func clearButtonRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        // change the return line as per your requirement. 
        return CGRect(x: 300, y: 25, width: 40, height: 20) 
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image: Output Image]

Hope this will help.

Comment: is there an easy way to find out the values for x, y, width and height?

Comment: My Textfields are already a subclass, so I copied your code into it but it does nothing, even with weird values.

Comment: override open func clearButtonRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: 0, y: 5.0, width: 10, height: 3)
    }

Comment: My Problem right now is, that my Textfields are already a subclass of TextFieldEffects. I just created the subclass CustomClearButton but how do I make it work now ?

Comment: @Chris if you run the application and follow this [Developer Tools for UI Debugging](https://medium.com/@dmytro.anokhin/overview-of-developer-tools-for-ui-debugging-122e4995f972) you will be able to find the x and y position

Comment: so, I did that and the effects are still working fine, but now the clear button doesn't even appear
`
import UIKit
import TextFieldEffects

class CustomTextField: HoshiTextField {

    
    override func clearButtonRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: 0, y: 5.0, width: 10, height: 3)
    }

}
`

Comment: as mentioned in the code you need to modify your `return CGRect(x: 0, y: 5.0, width: 10, height: 3)` to meet your needs. Have a look again to updated answer i have changed the return statement and added an image.

Answer (score 9):

You can create your own custom text field

Chirag's answer is correct but according to Apple, your method should call the super implementation and modify the returned rectangle’s origin only

```
class CustomTextField : UITextField
{
    override func clearButtonRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect{
        let rect = super.clearButtonRect(forBounds: bounds)
        return rect.offsetBy(dx: customX, dy: customY)
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please add the link to relevant apple document please?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619600-clearbuttonrect

Answer (score -1):

Building on the helpful answers here already...
And answering the comment about how to find the appropriate x/y position automatically. Here is my solution for a generic extension of the textfields from the TextFieldEffects library (I'm using the YoshikoTextField but the solution should work for any with a placeholder that floats above the field):

The textfields from that library have a placeholder rect that allows us to obtain the height of the upper part of the textfield, which is causing the wrong offset.

```
import UIKit
import TextFieldEffects

class CustomYoshikoTextField: YoshikoTextField {

    override func clearButtonRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        let rect = super.clearButtonRect(forBounds: bounds)
        let placeholderHeight = self.placeholderRect(forBounds: bounds).height
        return rect.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: placeholderHeight * 0.5)
    }
}
```

This is just moving the clear button down by half of the placholder rect height. Guaranteed to be centered on the actual input part of the field for any textfield size.