# Position UIButton in UITextview

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextfield

I would like to place a "forgot?" Button into my Password Textfield. If nothing is in the Textfield the user should be able to click it and another ViewController should pop up. The only thing I managed to do is what you can see in the picture down below. My problem is that the button is not clickable and that it is not on the same level as the placeholder text. Any ideas on how to solve this two problems?

```
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.setTitle("vergessen?", for: .normal)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(100), height: CGFloat(100))
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refresh), for: .touchUpInside)
    passwordTextField.rightView = button
    passwordTextField.rightViewMode = .unlessEditing
```

[image]

Comment: add your code for function `self.refresh`

Comment: You could use stackview. I will try to make an example.

Comment: @chirag90 i have this already:     
IBAction func refresh(_ sender: Any) {
    }
But it's not not connected to anything.  Where do I have to call self.refresh and how do I connect the IBAction to the Button?

Comment: how do I change the textFont and Size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file you have subclassed from my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57787873/4056108) add another function in that file

```
// Modify the values as required 
override func rightViewRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    let offset = -20
    let width  = 100
    let height = width
    let x = Int(bounds.width) - width - offset
    let y = offset
    let rightViewBounds = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
    return rightViewBounds
}
```

Now you can remove the follow line

```
button.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(100), height: CGFloat(100))
```

**Output**

[image: Output image]

And regarding the button click event. Remove your code as you mention its not connected

```
IBAction func refresh(_ sender: Any) { }
```

And add the following code in the same file where the button is created.

```
@objc func refresh() {
    // your vc code here
    print("in refresh")
}
```

The above code hooks in with addTarget code you have.

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refresh), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: and again, the perfect answer! Thanks! Could you maybe also tell me how to change the Text Size and Font ?:D

Comment: Textsize and font for button?

Comment: Yup you can do button.titlelabel.font = .systemFont(sizeOf : 12)

Comment: And for custom font you can do button.titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 20.0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Storyboard`. Make a helper view for the password `TextField` and Forgot `Button`.

-Set the Helper view same width and height with the email `TextField`.

-Add a `TextField` and a `Button` inside the helper view and then you can decide for the password `TextField` width and the Forgot `Button` width.
-Set constrains for the `TextField` and `Button`

[image]

I set green color to understand what the helper View does.

**Update**

I just used your code and it works fine.Check your textfield constrains again. This is what I used.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("vergessen?", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.3647058904, green: 0.06666667014, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(100), height: CGFloat(100))

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refresh), for: .touchUpInside)
        textfFeld.rightView = button
        textfFeld.rightViewMode = .unlessEditing
    }

    @objc func refresh(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Hello")
    }
```

The only think I changed is the button type from `.custom` to `.system`.

Comment: I'm sorry, kinda new to this. What exactly to do you mean by a Helper View?

Comment: @Chris Just to arrange the textfield and the button. First place the view make it same dimensions with email textField and inside that view place the password textfield and forgot button.

Comment: do you mean a stackview? or what "view"?:D

Comment: @Chris Just a normal UIView.

Comment: @Chis I just updated my answer. Check your TextField constrains.

Comment: its clickable now, but the hight is still the same problem as before

Comment: the only constraint is that its the same hight as the Email-TextField (60)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create a `xib` file and its relevant view for text items that have a button inside it. So you would be able to reuse it elsewhere in the future (this or another projects)

By defining constant height (100) you will experience ugly and misplaced UI in different iOS devices.
 Here it is what you should do :

1. Define a xib file for your custom `UITextView`
2. Create constraints for it so it width and height defined by its parent.Also define your forgot `UIButton` in relative to your `UITextView`.
3. Define its (xib) relevant `UIView` class
4. Use it in your `Storyboard`