# How can i set a Padding for the Text in UITextField

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to put the text in another position but I don't know how to do that? , There is no option to fix this issue on the Attributes Inspector?

See the | needs to be right where the arrow is pointing out:

[image]

Comment: You need to either give spaceing in Text or customised Textfield.

Comment: Probably you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53577179/3402095)

Answer (score 3):

You can make a custom padded TextField. You could try something like this

```
class PaddedTextFeild: UITextField {
    let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 5)
    override open func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.inset(by: padding)
    }
    override open func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.inset(by: padding)
    }
    override open func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.inset(by: padding)
    }
}
```

You could try using this class as it is. And change the UIEdgeInsets defined in the first line.